# What should be the required operating voltage for Servo motors in my 5 DOF robotic arm, with 50 kg payload

Tags: robotic-arm, servomotor, industrial-robot, electronics

These are the estimated torque values of all axis in our applications
1st Axis- 226.57 oz-in - 478oz-in
2nd Axis- 756 oz-in -1590oz-in
3rd Axis- 356 oz-in - 749.7 oz-in
4th Axis- 188 oz-in - 395 oz-inch
5th Axis-17.7oz-in - 37.2 oz-inches
Robot arm has to lift  payload of 50 kg, I want to source servo motors , for selection I am confused what operating voltage for servo motors would be suitable,DC or Ac and how much in Dc

Comment: Ah, let me see. Usually hobbyist grade servos use 5V to 6V. More serious applications use 7V to 12V. You can search "servo", "10kg", "50kg" to find any servo that meets your spec. You might also like to search "digital servo" to find heavy duty servos.

Comment: if we use Ac servos, would 400 v be convenient?

Comment: Ah, let see. 2000 oz-in = 144 kg-cm, and 150kg is the typical limit of 12V digital DC servo . Of course you can custom make bigger torques. For AC servos, you can easily find biggere torques over 200kg. It also depends on your torque/speed trade offs. And digital servo can have very fine position control, up to 2048 steps per revolution. AC servos can only do very coarse spec. Also you need to consider weight and space requirement. Again, google is your friend. Cheers.

Comment: yes,you are right, Thank you so much

Comment: You are welcome. Cheers.

Comment: Torque and force is controlled by current and gear ratios. Power is determined by acceleration of load. Voltage is only a factor when current gets large (e.g. :>10A) Does it move fast? Define your problem with torque and angular mass to compute angular force with mass and acceleration by design limits for starting and stopping. Then angular speed and momentum p=mv, F=ma and current/torque to reach that speed. These computations must be done before voltage and AC or DC are considered because acceleration of mass determines torque

Comment: Good answer @TonyStewartEE75.  Please make it a "real" answer so we can up-vote it and give you the reputation.   Comments are for helping to improve questions and answers, and are distracting, so we try to keep them to a minimum.

Comment: @Ben  A better Answer will result from a better question.  Muz* ought to refine his question 1st. *"Does it move fast? Define your problem with torque and angular mass to compute angular force with mass and acceleration by design limits"*  ( including momentum (p=mv) and gravitational energy (E=mgh))  Both energy and momentum must be conserved.  Servo specs must include seek time and 3D range. This implies torque, power and energy requirements or limits you impose by cost.  The question is trivialized and needs more detail.  But I suspect he is long gone.